# Pause the log4c++ logger

Tags: c++, logging

is it possible to pause the logger in log4c++, and by pause I mean to stop writing messages in the log file but not finalize the logger object or delete it.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can change the level with setLevel() to OFF